# Flickr-Android API : Oauth is not redirecting to 'grant-access' page

Tags: android, oauth, flickr

I'm developing an **Android** application which requires **Flickr API** integration. In previous days, I was able to successfully complete the oauth process. But now its not working, and I strongly believe it happend after flickr APIs changed from `http://` to `https://`

Let me explain the situation..

I'm following the steps explained in [Flickr API Doc](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html)

As a result of the call to `http://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/request_token` API, I'm successfully receiving the `oauth_token`.

After this step, I'm presenting Flickr authorization page in a webview with the url specified in API doc (which is somthing similar like, `https://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=72157626737672178-022bbd2f4c2f3432`, and of-course, with the `oauth_token` which I received in the previous step)

Few days before this call was working when I'm using `http://` instead of `https://`. But now, both `http://` and `https://` are not working. The page is displaying the login screen, but after successful login, the page is not redirecting to the *grant access* page, instead it is just redirecting to the *Flickr Home* page. And hence, I'm unable to grant access and unable to receive the `oauth_verifier`.

Hope I'm well explaining the situation which I'm facing now. But in short, Flickr Login for my application is not working, and I'm running out of time... :(

So, Geeks, Please give some light on the issue...

--Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried making the request for token over HTTPS?

Comment: Yes.. Currently I'm using all API calls over `HTTPS`

Comment: Hey all.. Seems like __Flickr fixes the issue__, and for this moment, __everything is perfect__. Thank you very much for all geeks who spend some time on this issue to give a helping hand.. Thanks again.. :)

Comment: @Midhu, I know its too late but some one helps. If you do auth with WebView make sure you enable javaScript.

WebSettings ws = webview.getSettings();

ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still the issue is there, After oauth Flickr is not redirecting to `grant_access` page. But I need to get the oauth process successfully completed in my on-going project, as soon as possible. So I have done a workaround to solve the issue.

To solve the '*not redirecting*' issue, I have done a little bit change in my `WebView`'s `WebViewClient` implementation. It's nothing great, but just redirecting to authorize page again, after successful login.

Authorize URL Example : `https://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=72157626737672178-022bbd2f4c2f3432`

So, given below is the detailed implementation of `WebViewClient`:

```
mAuthWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        showProgressDialog();

        /** TODO: This part should be deleted after flickr fixes the oauth redirection issue */ 
        if(url.endsWith("flickr.com/")) {
            mAuthWebView.loadUrl("https://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=72157626737672178-022bbd2f4c2f3432");
            return;
        }

        /* After successful login the redirected url will contain a parameter named 'oauth_verifier' */
        if (url.indexOf("oauth_verifier=") > -1) {
        /* Get the 'oauth_verifier' parameter from url and do next steps */
                performLoginSuccess();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        if (url.contains(_my_redirect_url_) && !url.contains("oauth_verifier=")) {
            /* User not authenticated our app */
            finish();
        } else if (!url.contains("oauth_verifier=")) {
            killProgressDialog();
        }
    }
});
```

After loading the authorization url, the web view will take the user to login page, and after user successfully loged into Flickr, with web vew client implementation we are again loading the authorization url, to present the grant access page.

```
mAuthWebView.loadUrl("https://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=72157626737672178-022bbd2f4c2f3432");
```

I know, this is not the right way to do this...
Any better solutions are always welcome.... :)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. I was using the connection in a WebView and my code was using the "http" protocol in the request.

I could resolve the issue by first using the "https" protocol for the authentification URL. As you say just doing that did not work. So I change the call of the url that was in the WebView and used the **ACTION_VIEW intent** and it worked.

Calling :

> startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(AuthentificationPath)));

Don't forget to implement the OnResume() function of your Activity to get the data of the returned intent.

Of course it is just a workaround but it does the job if you have to be fast.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Could you please confirm, whether this workaround requires Flickr Application to be installed on the device or not..??

Comment: This workaround works without FlickR Application installed on the device.

Comment: Hi @odore, Seems like the Flickr auth issue is fixed, and now there is no such problem. Thanks for giving a helping hand... :)